# JSON method POST with Alamofire and SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, alamofire, swift5, swifty-json

I'm trying to send data (parameters) into my local backend:

Here is some code:

Swift:

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["firstname": "User", "age": "33"]

        NetworkManager.sharedInstance.manager.request(localServer,
                                                      method: .post,
                                                      parameters: parameters,
                                                      encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                                                      headers: [:]).responseString { response in
            switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    print("JSON: \(json)")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
            }
        }
```

SQL-Table with needed attributes:

```
CREATE TABLE public.employee 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    firstName CHARACTER VARYING(30),
    tabel CHARACTER VARYING(30),
    age INTEGER,
    organization CHARACTER VARYING(30)
);
```

but only second parameter **AGE** sends into backend. Parameter **FIRSTNAME** is Null :(

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: You are sending "firstname" but in table, you declare column as "firstName", see N is capital

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the **alias** on the Application Server Side:

```
api.post("/employee/req", jsonParser, function(request, response){
        let { name, age } = request.body;
        pool.query('insert into public.employee (firstname, age) values ($1, $2)', [name, age], (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                throw error
            }
            response.status(201).send('User added')
        })
```